# Varnish cache with Nginx SSL termination

Tags: nginx, wordpress, cache, varnish, ubuntu-18.04

How can I use varnish cache with nginx SSL termination for my SSL-Only (Https only) website? I use ubuntu 18.04 and I am currently running a wordpress site on my server.

Comment: i aint know for what you want to use vanish, if you want to use caching use nginx directly

Comment: Varnish caching is more faster compared to nginx caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sofar I add the complete way

> mkdir /var/cache/nginx/cache 
>    chown nginx:nginx /var/cache/nginx/cache

Now Edit nginx.conf below the http  section

```
###New cache settings as default
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=hd_cache:10m max_size=10g inactive=2d use_temp_path=off;
proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;
proxy_cache_valid 200 302 3d;
proxy_cache_valid 404      1m;
```

edit /etc/nginx/sites-avaible/yoursite.com

```
#http to https redirect
server {
        server_name yoursite.com *.yoursite.com;
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

#https server
server {
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name yoursite.com *.yoursite.com;

#a special location in case don't cache this file can be deleted
location updater/serversettings.xml {
          expires -1;
          add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        }

                #The root/rest will be redirected
                location / {
                        proxy_cache             hd_cache;
                        proxy_set_header        X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
                        proxy_cache_valid       200 1w;
                        proxy_pass              https://10.10.200.4;
                        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
                        proxy_buffers           16 8m;
                        proxy_buffer_size       2m;
                        gzip on;
                        gzip_vary          on;
                        gzip_comp_level    9;
                        gzip_proxied       any;
}
    #SSL Cert section, as we require ssl, using certbot LetsEncrypt
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yoursite.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yoursite.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Now Enable this site.

> ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-avaible/yoursite.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yoursite.com

and run

> service Nginx reload

This Setup works fine for a WordPress site, I encounter a page speed counter of 95+

Comment: @RahulBiswas you can safely remove vanish, as it only doubles the interaction. see my answer to speed up

Comment: Yeah....i have removed Varnish now...

Comment: and if the config helped you, i would be hsppy about an upvote and accept as answer

Comment: My upvotes won't be public before 15 reps...but answer def. accepted!

Comment: thanks, that setup i also use for any other sites i host and it pumping the stuff out, even i ran for each site an contsiner on my proxmox host