# How to properly setup Nginx as a reverse proxy behind a load balancer which routes all Wordpress requests to external server?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, load-balancing, wordpress

We have an existing SPA application running on server #1. We built out a Wordpress site hosted on a Kinsta server (server #2). Marketing wants to launch the new site and direct 50% of traffic to it while directing 50% of traffic to the old SPA.

My solution: I set up a load balancer using Cloudflare to split the traffic between the two servers equally. This works great. I then needed to have server #1 (existing Nginx configured as reverse-proxy) handle all requests for /wp-* and send them to server #2.

My current Nginx location block

```
location ~* /wp-(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass         https://{{server #2 ip address}}/wp-$1$is_args$args;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

The problem: While this somewhat works, many of the requested files return a 404 while some others load fine. Here are some example urls and their status codes.

https://{{domainname}}/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/css/dist/wpseo-dismissible-1500.css 200
https://{{domainname}}/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/js/admin.min.js 404

I've checked that both of these files exist on server #2 which they do.

Can anyone recommend an Nginx config that will work for this problem? I toyed around with using rewrite and a 302 (didn't try 301) but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/980184/varnish-cache-with-nginx-ssl-termination/980272#980272 take a look at my one

Comment: Interesting. And that worked for you? Are you running a similar setup?

Comment: this is the current configuration i use